# iTerm2 more contrast to active tab

Tags: iterm

Is there a way using iTerm2 to give the active tab more contrast compared to the rest of the tabs?

[image: showing active tab]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can choose a Tab Style in the preferences, under the "Appearance" pane.

The standard styles "Metal" and "Unified" appear to offer better contrast for the active tab than the other two. From your screenshot, it appears you have selected "Adium" which does indeed have very poor contrast.

[image: iTerm2 Preferences]

Comment: I just found this.  Adium was set for me by default, I never picked it.  Feel stupid for not finding it myself earlier :)

Answer (score 3):

One workaround I found is to set the tab color to a pale and greyish color e.g. `47736b` in Profile->Colors->Tab Color and have Light High Contrast theme active. The active tab will have a light bright color.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the setting *Advanced → Tab → "How prominent .. outline around selected tab .." set to largest (3)*  makes the selected tab most obvious.

[image]